# Yii2 Title from Breadcrumbs?

Tags: format, yii2, title, breadcrumbs

I want to make a title from my breadcrumbs in reverse order.
So in my breadcrumbs the link is: `www.example.com/provider/room/room1`. From this I want to create `"Room1 - Room - Provider"` title.
Someone can help me, how can i do this? Is there some options in breadcrumbs widget to do this? Because I don't know much about breadcrumbs and breadcrumbs widget and I didn't find something like this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply code in reverse order

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'voice1'), 'url' => ['index1']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'voice2'), 'url' => ['index2']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'voice3'), 'url' => ['index3']];
```

voice1 - voice2 - voice3

or

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'voice3'), 'url' => ['index3']]; 
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'voice2'), 'url' => ['index2']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'voice1'), 'url' => ['index1']];
```

voice3 - voice2 -voice1

For the title name in variable (eg: $titleName) and url form db (eg: $model->url) this could be the template

```
$myUrl = Url::to(['/yourController/' . $model->url])

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $titleName, 'url' => [$myUrl]];
```

Comment: Ok, but my title name cames from a variable, and the parent urls cames from a database.
So when i click to view a room detail in the title i want to show the room provider or owner.

Comment: I have update the asnwer.. adding the info about your comment. Is however a good practice don't change or add new questions. Eventually post a new question. And if a question is right if fair  mark it as accepted.